# Disable all logging at once in logback.xml

Tags: java, logging, logback

How can I disable all logging at once in my application if I am using logback as the backend? I can only disable loggers one by one setting them to level="off". Is there something I can do to disable all logging at once while individual loggers are set to other than "off"?

Thanks,

EDIT, this is my actual file:

```
<configuration level="OFF">

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>log/app.log</file>
    <append>false</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>[%level] [%d{dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%thread] [%logger] %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNCFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </appender>

  <appender name="DISTRIBUTION_TRACE_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>log/distribution_trace.log</file>
    <append>false</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%message</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="DISTRIBUTION_TRACE_FILE_ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="DISTRIBUTION_TRACE_FILE" />
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>[%level] [%d{dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%thread] [%logger] %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </appender>

  <logger name="app.logger" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCFILE"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="distribution.logger" level="ALL">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="distribution.trace" level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="DISTRIBUTION_TRACE_FILE_ASYNC"/>
  </logger>

  <root level="OFF">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have something that is called the `root` logger. Set level to `off` on root logger and you are done. This is example snippet from my `logback.xml` configuration file.

```
<root level="DEBUG"> <!-- set this to OFF and no more logging-->
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="DAYFILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="DAYFILE_WARN" />
        <appender-ref ref="ELASTIC" />
</root>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. I have added the configuration I am using. I'd appreciate your review